# Passing Parameter to a Named Function with Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have an angular app and I'm passing a named function into a controller. The problem is I want to inject a provider into that controller to use. The console gives me `TypeError: object is not a function`.

My question is, what's wrong with my syntax? Am I thinking of this the wrong way?

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('MyCoolApp.controllers')

  .controller('SignInCtrl', ['$scope', 'Avatar', SignInCtrl]);

  function SignInCtrl(Avatar) {
    var vm = this;

    // Error occurs here in reference to creating an instance of Avatar
    vm.avatar = new Avatar();
  }
})();
```

Comment: Arguments in the DI list must match number and order in the constructor.

Comment: I've seen it where $scope is not required as a parameter in the named function. Am I wrong?

Comment: You should [read this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First argument is `$scope` not `Avatar`

```
function SignInCtrl($scope, Avatar) {
    var vm = this;

    // Error occurs here in reference to creating an instance of Avatar
    vm.avatar = new Avatar();
}
```